# Implementation of SignalR 2 using CORS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cors, signalr

I have an application running on port 64999 ,
which is making signal call to another application running on different port 65420

On Startup of application having port 65420 I have code:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        app.Map("/signalR", map =>
        {
            map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

            var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
            {
                EnableJSONP = true,
                EnableDetailedErrors=true
            };
            map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
        });
    }

}
```

From application 64999 I'm trying to make connection to another application like:

```
    var connection =$.hubConnection('http://localhost:65420/signalR/hubs');
    var chatHubProxy = connection.createHubProxy('chatHub');

    chatHubProxy.on('getDetails', function (message) {

        $("#Message").html(message);
    });

    connection.start().done(function () {
        chatHubProxy.invoke('sendMessage', "Hello");
    });
```

I'm not able to understand how to make any call to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really searched across the internet and found answer in https://cmatskas.com/signalr-cross-domain-with-cors/.

What I have did now is changed the location of hub in application 64999

```
  <script src="http://localhost:65420/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

and my javascript code is like :

```
    $.connection.hub.url = 'http://localhost:65420/signalr';
    var chat= $.connection.chatHub;
    chat.client.getDetails = function (car, speed, overSpeed) {
        $("#Message").html(message);
    };

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        chat.server.sendMessage("Hello World");
    });
```